# Необходимо, чтобы элемент "GENERAL", после того, как убран класс, появился мгновенно

Tags: javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (isOnScreen(jQuery('.MARSHAL'))) {
      $('.GENERAL').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("$('.GENERAL').removeClass('RJADOVOJ')", 300);
      } else {
    $('.GENERAL').addClass('RJADOVOJ');
   }
});
```

Необходимо, чтобы элемент "GENERAL", после того, как убран класс, появился мгновенно. Спасибо за советы.

Comment: А что делает `isOnScreen`? Желательно привести код.

Comment: А сейчас он вообще появляется? Наверно надо добавить после removeClass внутри setTimeout строку $('.GENERAL').show();

Comment: Сейчас он не появляется, если убрать фейд- всё работает. Такую строку пробовал, тогда он повторяет эту функцию, пока маршал на экране. Маргает элемент постоянно..

Comment: isOndcreen отслеживает положение элемента, в каком бы месте он не находился.